# Can someone tell me the pros and cons of Ranorex and with coded UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, ranorex

I am testing a Web application and stated using `Ranorex`.  It is easy to use.  Then there is a suggestion of Coded `U`I.  Can someone tell me the pros and cons of `Ranorex` and with coded `UI`?

Answer (score 0):

Easy:  Ranorex can be used by non-programmers! (or by people with little programming knowledge)

Programmers are usually very though to hire for tests.

As for Coded UI (I assume in Visual Studio), it is more tedious and requires programming skills.

I have personally done this comparison and came to the conclusion that a tool must be used for automation (even if I am a programmer).

Then, we chose Ranorex but there are other tools which are doing very good job. We chose Ranorex because it supports all the technologies we use (Web, Android, iOS and WinForms) and it support standard .NET programming (which is a language that we use internally).

In the end, it all depends on your test automation budget!